# C# pure R6025 virtual function call

Tags: c#, function, call, virtual

i get the following error on my live System (Windows Server 2012 R2 x64) but not on my dev (Windows 7 x64) machine. Another stackoverflow thread said "[you are calling a function that is declared, but since you are not calling any child's implementation, it has no definition.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5688330/2599603)". Wouldn't the IDE show such declared functions as a warning? I've also read that the Version of .net might be the Problem, so i've updated to 4.5.2; to no avail. My Project runs on .net Version 4.
Any idea how to debug/solve this kind of problem?

[image: Error description: Runtime Error! R6025 - pure virtual function call]

EDIT to clarify:

1. I don't know what code is throwing because it only happens on the live system
2. I'm sure it's C# code if it's any of mine (3 Projects all in C#). But i'm referencing a COM component, which might be the problem. But why only on live and not on my dev machine?
3. no 'virtual' keyword to be found anywhere in the code.

Comment: what code is throwing ?

Comment: Are you sure that the code is C#? If I remember well, it is impossible to have a pure virtual function call in C#. Maybe you are calling some COM components?

Comment: It certainly sounds like some native code is involved somewhere...

Comment: seems to be a duplicate to  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/464311/pure-virtual-function-call-message-box

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i narrowed it down to a COM-Component which seems to have a problem with Windows Server 2012 R2.
Because it's a problem with a 3rd Party i've contacted them to fix the problem.